# How to calculate the average of the selected attribute in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I am working on the Fifa 19 Kaggle Dataset. I want to create a Gauge chart that compares the Overall stat for a Player compared with the Overall Average of the club(target value) he plays for.

I tried to create a calculated column:

```
Club Overall = calculate(Average(data[Overall]); data[Club]= "FC Barcelona")
```

Instead of "FC Barcelona", I want it to be the Club the selected player plays in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This measure should do what you want, by filtering all players, but leaving the club filter in place:

```
Club Overall Average = 
IF ( 
    HASONEVALUE ( data[Club] ),
    CALCULATE ( 
        AVERAGE ( data[Overall] ),
        ALL ( data[Name] ),
        data[Club] = VALUES ( data[Club] )
    ),
    BLANK()
)
```

See https://pwrbi.com/2019/05/stack-overflow-56128872/ for worked example